# In odoo ,I select all the records in page 1 then navigating to page 2 all records in unselected, how to fix

Tags: python, odoo, flectra

Good day, Hello friends, I'm having this issue when trying to select all the records in the page 1, then when going to the page 2 all of the records in this page is unselected. Can someone help me to fix this and select all the records when paginating to the other page. Thank you in advance. Here is the video that you can view for reference.

https://vimeo.com/680283107

Answer (score 1):

One way to select all records is to modify the number of records displayed to be a range from the first record to the last records, which will result in getting all record in one page.

You can change at the area I pointed here from "6-10" to "1-10" because you have total of 10 records.

[image: reference]